# How do I make the legends tab focusable in a chart.js Line chart using React.js?

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, accessibility, linechart

I'm trying to make all my clickable elements "tab-able" or keyboard-only accessible. Is there a way to give tabIndex to the individual legends in chart.js? This is my first time using chart.js and I've been trying to look for solutions.

Here's my LineChart component:

```
`import { Typography } from "@mui/material";
import { Line } from "react-chartjs-2";
import {
  Chart as ChartJS,
  LineElement,
  CategoryScale, //x axis
  LinearScale, //y axis
  PointElement,
  Legend,
  Tooltip,
} from "chart.js";

ChartJS.register(
  LineElement,
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  PointElement,
  Legend,
  Tooltip
);

const LineChart = ({ data, setData, showChart, setShowChart }) => {
  const style = {
    width: "50%",
    margin: "0 auto",
    color: "#0064A1",
  };
  const options = {
    plugins: {
      legend: true,
      tabIndex: 0,
    },
    scales: {
      y: {
        min: 0.0,
        // max: 1,
      },
    },
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div style={style}>
        <Typography variant="h2" align="center">
          Probability History
        </Typography>
        <Line data={data} options={options}></Line>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default LineChart;`
```

My datasets are in a different component. I tried giving component tabIndex but it just made the whole chart tab-able.

Comment: You should not add a chart’s elements in the tab order, since it adds a lot of tab stops to the page. Establishing a [_composite widget_](https://w3c.github.io/aria/#composite) would be recommended, which only has one tab stop, and then uses _arrow keys_ to navigate the legends.

Comment: In general, it is quite impossible to render a 3rd party library accessible through its API, if it‘s not accessible already. According to [Charts.js Accessibility](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/accessibility.html), it is rendered in a `<canvas>`, so you cannot simply work with HTML attributes to render elements focusable. If it’s not build in, you don’t have a chance.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to see if I could build a plugin to help address this issue for you. The plugin is chartjs-plugin-a11y-legend, and I have it working with some basic examples and vanilla chart.js.

Here are examples with keyboard navigation if you want to play with them.
https://codepen.io/chart2music/full/ZEMyLVZ

You would be able to use the plugin by just importing the plugin and registering it. So:

```js
// Import the plugin
import plugin from "chartjs-plugin-a11y-legend";
// Import from Chartjs as normal
import {
  Chart as ChartJS,
  LineElement,
  CategoryScale, //x axis
  LinearScale, //y axis
  PointElement,
  Legend,
  Tooltip,
} from "chart.js";

// Register all of the normal Chartjs things
ChartJS.register(
  LineElement,
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  PointElement,
  Legend,
  Tooltip,

  // and register the plugin
  plugin
);
```

I haven't tested it with react-chartjs-2. If it doesn't work with that... if you can provide me a codepen or codesandbox, I'll try to get it sorted out.